# Breeze odata and collections

Tags: collections, breeze

I am trying to fetch metadata from odata server, in which one of the entities has

```
<Property Name="StakeHoldersLGIds" Type="Collection(Edm.Int32)" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="CollaboratorsLGIds" Type="Collection(Edm.Int32)" Nullable="false"/>
```

it failes to parse the metadata. I saw that in the parsing Breeze treats it as simpleItems cause there is the . and the parsing returns array of 2.

```
var typeParts = csdlProperty.type.split(".");
    if (typeParts.length === 2) {
        dp = parseCsdlSimpleProperty(parentType, csdlProperty, keyNamesOnServer);
```

and this looks like a bug, is there a work around?

Comment: What is generating the OData metadata? i.e. WCF Data services, WebApi OData, Sharepoint ... etc.

Comment: Webapi version 2 odata

Comment: WebApi 2 OData is actually broken ( MS metadata impl is not per spec) We will be providing guidance ( and code ) showing how to fix this within the next week or so.  Until then you can use WCF DataServices.

Comment: also for the collection? cause this is the only problem i have